# How to make the suggestions menu appear automatically for all kind of files?

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-code

I would like to have an automatic drop down menu with the suggestions of possible words whenever I write something, but not when I am in Javascript, HTML or CSS mode (it already pops up automatically), but in a plain text file.

Is that possible to do?

I have tried to look at the settings file, but I have not found how to do it. 
Usually I have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, and a pop up menus appears with some suggestions based on what you have typed so far (I guess).

Answer (score 1):

VSCode doesn't currently support this. However, you can workaround using the following rules in your `keybindings.json`:

`File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts`

```
[
{ "key": "a", "command": "^editor.action.triggerSuggest", "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "b", "command": "^editor.action.triggerSuggest", "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "c", "command": "^editor.action.triggerSuggest", "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "d", "command": "^editor.action.triggerSuggest", "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "e", "command": "^editor.action.triggerSuggest", "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "f", "command": "^editor.action.triggerSuggest", "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "g", "command": "^editor.action.triggerSuggest", "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "h", "command": "^editor.action.triggerSuggest", "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "i", "command": "^editor.action.triggerSuggest", "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "j", "command": "^editor.action.triggerSuggest", "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "k", "command": "^editor.action.triggerSuggest", "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "l", "command": "^editor.action.triggerSuggest", "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "m", "command": "^editor.action.triggerSuggest", "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "n", "command": "^editor.action.triggerSuggest", "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "o", "command": "^editor.action.triggerSuggest", "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "p", "command": "^editor.action.triggerSuggest", "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "q", "command": "^editor.action.triggerSuggest", "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "r", "command": "^editor.action.triggerSuggest", "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "s", "command": "^editor.action.triggerSuggest", "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "t", "command": "^editor.action.triggerSuggest", "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "u", "command": "^editor.action.triggerSuggest", "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "v", "command": "^editor.action.triggerSuggest", "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "w", "command": "^editor.action.triggerSuggest", "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "x", "command": "^editor.action.triggerSuggest", "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "y", "command": "^editor.action.triggerSuggest", "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "z", "command": "^editor.action.triggerSuggest", "when": "editorTextFocus" }
]
```